# Using CLAPACK undefined reference error

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to get clapack working on ubuntu 14... But it keeps telling me undefined reference to "ssyev_"(actually it happens to any of those c functions in "clapack.h")

I just used the cmd "g++ lineartest3.cpp -o linear3"

I am pretty sure i followed the instructions shown below.

- cd CLAPACK-3.2.1
- cp make.inc.example make.inc
- make f2clib
- make blaslib
- make (this takes a while)
- sudo cp INCLUDE/f2c.h /usr/include
- sudo cp INCLUDE/clapack.h /usr/include
- sudo chmod 644 /usr/include/f2c.h
- sudo chmod 644 /usr/include/clapack.h**

And my little codes.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" {               
#include "f2c.h"           
#include "clapack.h"       
}


int main()
{
int i,j;
float *A = new float[16];
A[0] = 1; A[1] = 1; A[2] = 1;  A[3] = 1;
A[4] = 1; A[5] = 2; A[6] = 3;  A[7] = 4;
A[8] = 1; A[9] = 3; A[10]= 6;  A[11]= 10;
A[12]= 1; A[13]= 4; A[14]= 10; A[15]= 20;
cout << "A = (";
for (i=0; i<15; i++) cout << A[i] << ",";
cout << A[15] << ")" << endl;

// use call-by-reference parameters, in another adaptation to Fortran
int n = 4;
char jobz = 'V';
char uplo = 'U';
integer N = n;
integer LDA=n;
float* eigvalue=new float[n]; 
int worksize;    // must have lwork>=3n-1, so n^2 is not big enough for n=2!
if (n==2) worksize = 5; else worksize = n*n;
float *work; 
work=new float[worksize];
integer lwork = worksize;
integer info;    // exit status

ssyev_(&jobz, &uplo, &N, A, &LDA, eigvalue, work, &lwork, &info);

cout << "info = " << info << endl;
if (info>=0)

{

    cout << "Eigenvalues = (" 

     << eigvalue[0] << "," << eigvalue[1] << "," 

     << eigvalue[2] << "," << eigvalue[3] << ")" << endl;

    cout << "Correct answer in GvL: (.0380, .4538, 2.2034 (typo?), 26.3047)" 

     << endl;

    // eigenvectors are stored in A (overwriting the original matrix):

    // ith eigenvector = ith column of A

    for (i=0; i<4; i++)

      {

    cout << "Eigenvector " << i << " = (";
    for (j=0; j<3; j++)
      cout << A[j+i*4] << ","; // jth elt of ith col=jth elt of ith evector
    cout << A[3+i*4] << ")" << endl;
      }
}
delete [] A;
delete [] eigvalue;  // be a good boy scout
delete [] work;
return 0;

}
```

Plz help ..

Comment: Why did you make code two times longer with all these empty lines?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.. I have to say the documents for beginners are terrible...

copy blas_LINUX.a   lapack_LINUX.a  F2CLIBS/libf2c.a to /usr/local/lib and rename to libblas.a liblapack.a libf2c.a separately.

change the permission "chmod 777 libblas.a liblapack.a libf2c.a"

write a test.cpp and call "g++ test.cpp -llapack -lblas -lf2c -o test"

Comment: Well, I would not use 777 for permission... 644 is much better for a library.