# how to build g++ Makefile

Tags: makefile, g++

Last time i asked sth about how to use CLAPACK.
[Using CLAPACK undefined reference error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431024/using-clapack-undefined-reference-error)

After that i tried to separate everything for a larger project.

Now I have "blitzLA.cpp" "InterfaceCLAPACK.cpp" "InterfaceCLAPACK.hpp"

I could successfully make it work just by calling

```
g++ -Wall -g InterfaceCLAPACK.cpp blitzLA.cpp -llapack -lblas -lf2c -o blitzLA
```

But if I do the Makefile, it gives me some errors.. My makefile is shown below.

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
linker = -llapack -lblas -lf2c
blitzLA: blitzLA.o InterfaceCLAPACK.o 
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} InterfaceCLAPACK.o blitzLA.o -o blitzLA
blitzLA.o: blitzLA.cpp InterfaceCLAPACK.hpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${linker} -c blitzLA.cpp
InterfaceCLAPACK.o: InterfaceCLAPACK.cpp InterfaceCLAPACK.hpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${linker} -c InterfaceCLAPACK.cpp
clean:  
    rm -rf *.o blitzLA
```

I guess the problem is where do i leave "-llapack -lblas -lf2c"..Now i get the errors shown below.

```
g++ -Wall -g -llapack -lblas -lf2c -c blitzLA.cpp
g++ -Wall -g -llapack -lblas -lf2c -c InterfaceCLAPACK.cpp
g++ -Wall -g InterfaceCLAPACK.o blitzLA.o -o blitzLA
InterfaceCLAPACK.o: In function `quantfin::interfaceCLAPACK::SolveLinear(blitz::Array<double, 2>
```

bunch of things here..

```
/home/baozi/Dropbox/Linux/LinearAlgebra/InterfaceCLAPACK.cpp:64: undefined reference to `dgttrf_'
/home/baozi/Dropbox/Linux/LinearAlgebra/InterfaceCLAPACK.cpp:67: undefined reference to `dgttrs_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blitzLA] Error 1
```

Where do i go wrong.. Help plz

Comment: what are the errors you're getting?

Comment: @MoKi Now I only have two ${linker} in the Makefile as shown above.After call make I get....
InterfaceCLAPACK.o: In function'......undefined reference to `dgttrf_'   ...So the problem is not able to link correctly

Comment: @MoKi Error updated. I guess it's where to add "-llapack -lblas -lf2c"(which are all static locak .a files)

Comment: `$ \`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus\` -v` use this to see your compiler search path.

Comment: You need `${linker}` on the link line. Right now you have them on the compile lines which is doing nothing for you. Remove it from the two `.o` target bodies and add it to the `blitzLA` target body.

Comment: @EtanReisner it did't work ,besides undefined reference, it gives "/home/baozi/Dropbox/Linux/LinearAlgebra/blitzLA.cpp:9: multiple definition of `main'
//usr/local/lib/libf2c.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
//usr/local/lib/libf2c.a(main.o): In function `main':
(.text.startup+0x87): undefined reference to `MAIN__'"....

Comment: Could you show us the new `blitzLA` rule?